# регулярные выражения - неизвестно будет ли слово

Tags: php

Как указать, что какой-то участок в регулярном выражении, может быть, а может и не быть...

1 2 3 456 7 8

456 может не быть

[456]? - ?

Comment: $info_curl = "123 456 789 0 ";
$info_curl .= "123 456 789 0 ";
$info_curl .= "123 456 0 ";
$info_curl .= "123 456 789 0 ";
$info_curl .= "123 456 789 0 ";
$info_curl .= "123 456 0 ";
$info_curl .= "123 456 789 0 ";

preg_match("@123 (456)[ 789|] 0@u", $info_curl, $out);

print_r($out);

Comment: Необходимо это указать, но не получать этот фрагмент в ответе, т .е. ( фрагмент|) не подходит

Answer (score 0):

Может не правильно понял суть вопроса:

```
preg_match('/1 2 3 (456 |)7 8/',$str);

// 1 2 3 456 7 8 - true
// 1 2 3 7 8 - true
// 1 2 3 999 7 8 - false
```

Comment: либо без "или" можно так `.. (456 )? ..`

Comment: @Lexx918 нет, нельзя

Comment: тесты и здравый смысл говорят об обратном https://regex101.com/r/6bMxX3/1

Comment: @Lexx918 я не понял что вопросительный знак у тебя часть кода, а не вопрос :) Вставил бы все выражение, а не кусок было бы видно

Answer (score 0):

> *Как указать, что какой-то участок в регулярном выражении, может быть, а может и не быть*

Используйте группировку символов в не сохраняющих скобках `(?:`**...**`)`. В состав шаблона будут входить следующие элементы:

одна или более цифр

```
\d+(?:\h\d{3})*\h\d
^^^
```

за которыми следует НЕ обязательная *(`*` - ноль и более совпадений)* группа символов

```
\d+(?:\h\d{3})*\h\d
   ^^^       ^^
```

состоящих из одного пробела и трёх цифр

```
\d+(?:\h\d{3})*\h\d
      ^^^^^^^
```

за пределами группы должен быть один пробел и одна цифра

```
\d+(?:\h\d{3})*\h\d
               ^^^^
```

См. [демо шаблона](https://regex101.com/r/1dQ4XM/1/)

---

Целиком решение будет выглядеть так:

```
$info_curl = "123 456 789 0 123 456 789 0 123 456 0 123 456 789 0 123 456 789 0 123 456 0 123 456 789 0 ";

$patt = '~\d+(?:\h\d{3})*\h\d~';
preg_match_all($patt, $info_curl, $out);

print_r($out[0]);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123 456 789 0
    [1] => 123 456 789 0
    [2] => 123 456 0
    [3] => 123 456 789 0
    [4] => 123 456 789 0
    [5] => 123 456 0
    [6] => 123 456 789 0
)
```

См. [демо php-кода](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74e17d326558b4641c7a0dcaa85915d52b0ced77)

> *Для запуска кода по этой ссылке нужно кликнуть по кнопке **Execute Code***